# Ошибка: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

Tags: python, telegram-bot, callback

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия пользователем in-line клавиатуры, я хочу вывести результат, из функции answer, но мне выдаёт ошибку:

A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

Но если я присваиваю следующее состояние(белый скриншот), то все работает.
Как сделать так, чтобы все работало и выдавало результат без лишних действий ?

1)

```
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'highprice' or call.data == 'lowprice',                   state=MyStates.user_choice)
@logger.catch
def high_low_button(call: CallbackQuery):
with bot.retrieve_data(call.message.chat.id, call.message.chat.id) as data:
    if call.data == "highprice":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>Вы выбрали сортировку по возрастанию цены!</b>")
        data["user_choice"] = "highprice"
        data['sort'] = "PRICE_HIGHEST_FIRST"
        data['filters'] = {'availableFilter': 'SHOW_AVAILABLE_ONLY'}
    elif call.data == "lowprice":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>Вы выбрали сортировку по убыванию цены!</b>")
        data["user_choice"] = "lowprice"
        data['sort'] = "PRICE_LOW_TO_HIGH"
        data['filters'] = {'availableFilter': 'SHOW_AVAILABLE_ONLY'}

    give_an_answer.answer(call.message, data)
```

2. 

```
 @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'highprice' or call.data == 'lowprice',
                            state=MyStates.user_choice)
@logger.catch
def high_low_button(call: CallbackQuery):
    with bot.retrieve_data(call.message.chat.id, call.message.chat.id) as data:
        if call.data == "highprice":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>Вы выбрали сортировку по возрастанию цены!</b>")
            data["user_choice"] = "highprice"
            data['sort'] = "PRICE_HIGHEST_FIRST"
            data['filters'] = {'availableFilter': 'SHOW_AVAILABLE_ONLY'}
        elif call.data == "lowprice":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>Вы выбрали сортировку по убыванию цены!</b>")
            data["user_choice"] = "lowprice"
            data['sort'] = "PRICE_LOW_TO_HIGH"
            data['filters'] = {'availableFilter': 'SHOW_AVAILABLE_ONLY'}

    bot.set_state(call.from_user.id, MyStates.sort, call.message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "<b>Продолжить?</b>")


@bot.message_handler(state=MyStates.sort)
@logger.catch
def get_result(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.text.isalpha():
        with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
            give_an_answer.answer(message, data)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)